# python typeerror unbound method emit must be called with streamhandler instance as fistr argument (got filehandler instance instead)

Tags: python

python module **paramiko** throw a strange exception as shown on the tile. And finally I find the position it really occurs which is in the module **logging**. when I set a breakpoint on the line in Eclipse with pydev, and put lines below in the **expressions** view, the evaluated value confused me. I wonder that in what circumstance the exception may happen, though it's impossible from my view.

```
self.__class__ # <class 'logging.FileHandler'>
isinstance(self, FileHandler)  # False
isinstance(self, StreamHandler) # False
```

emit method of FileHandler:

```
def emit(self, record):
    """
    Emit a record.

    If the stream was not opened because 'delay' was specified in the
    constructor, open it before calling the superclass's emit.
    """
    if self.stream is None:
        self.stream = self._open()
    StreamHandler.emit(self, record)
```

Comment: not enough context to answer this question. Show a minimal program which leads to this error.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry I have not found  the _context_, but it's what I ask for and what I have been digging into my project to find. I will update the post when I find any other glue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally fixed it.
Reloading the module `logging` caused this issue.